# Sqlite3 How to Indentify the table locking status then insert

Tags: c, linux, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 3.6.23.1 version in fedora linux.I have two threads running to access the database.There is a chance that both thread will try perform write operation in the same table.

Table gets locked when first thread is performing write operation.How do i handle this case.

Is there any C,sqlite3 API mechanism like wait and then write into the table until another threads is completing write operation.

Thanks & Regards.

-praveen

Answer (score 1):

There is a "shared cache" mode which can be set via the C API as described [here](http://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html).

Sqlite3 does a good job of maximizing concurrency and it is also thread-safe. See the [File Locking and Concurrency document](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) for more details.

The table does indeed get locked for the duration of the write operation, but sqlite3 is able to navigate this condition by waiting for the lock to be released and then the lock is granted to the second process/thread wanting to perform a write (or read). The time-out for waiting for a lock can be configured in your sqlite connection code. Here is the syntax for Python 2.7:

```
sqlite3.connect(database[, timeout, detect_types, isolation_level, 
                check_same_thread, factory, cached_statements])
```

The default timeout is 5.0 seconds. So it would take a fairly bulky SELECT or COMMIT transaction to hold a lock for that amount of time. Based on your use-case you could, however, tweak the timeout OR include code to catch timeout exceptions.

A final option would be to incorporate some kind of flagging mechanism in your code that requires competing threads to wait until a flag clears before attempting to access the DB, but this duplicates the effort of the sqlite3 developers who have catered for concurrency scenarios as a major part of their job.

Here is an interesting article outlining a problem whereby [older versions of sqlite may sleep for a whole second](http://beets.radbox.org/blog/sqlite-nightmare.html) when unable to acquire a lock.